# How to search a specific value in 2 tables and copy to a new sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to achieve the following.

Using one unique identifier to search across another reference table and printing the entire row into a fresh sheet.

I am stuck at the 2nd for loop, looping across a column to get the unique identifier.

Hope someone can help me out.

_____Edit_____

I think I was too vague in my request so I decided to make it pictorial.

[Pictorial Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apc85.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Worksheets("Dependency Table").Range("A2:K99").ClearContents
a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To a

If ActiveCell.value = Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(i, 1).value Then

    For k = 1 To 5

        If Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(Selection.Row, k).value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).value Then

                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
                Worksheets("Dependency Table").Activate
                b = Worksheets("Dependency Table").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Worksheets("Dependency Table").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Worksheets("Dependency Table").Activate

        End If

    Next

End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You dont need to do the copy, you can just say `destrange.value=sourcerange.value`

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. I wouldn't use ActiveCell in your code though (particularly as you are selecting other cells later on).

Comment: Apologies for the request being vague, I've added a picture to make it clearer.

Comment: It's not clear 1) which cells must be copied from Dependency Matrix and 2) what result should be (the picture shows just empty table).

Comment: The cells to be copied is from "Sheet1" to the Dependency Table. The matrix is to document what dependencies each SKU has. I will update the picture to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have reversed the row in the compared cells in the second for loop

Instead of:

`If Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(Selection.Row, k).value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).value Then`

try:

`If Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(i, k).value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Selection.Row, 4).value Then`

Also, as Nathan said in questions, you shouldn't have to select/copy/past, instead just set new range equal to the range in the column inside the for statement.

`Worksheets("Dependency Table").Cells(b + 1 &":"& b+1).value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i &":"& i).value`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to achieve what I intended. Albeit the method might be a little rudimentary.

Decided not to do the `destrange.value=sourcerange.value` yet. Just needed a quick fix to make this work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Worksheets("Dependency Table").Range("A2:K99").ClearContents
a = Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
d = Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column

For i = 1 To a

If ActiveCell.Value = Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(i, 1).Value Then

    For k = 1 To 30

        For r = 1 To c

            If Worksheets("Dependency Matrix").Cells(i, k).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value Then

                Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(r).Copy
                Worksheets("Dependency Table").Activate
                b = Worksheets("Dependency Table").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Worksheets("Dependency Table").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste

             End If
        Next

    Next

End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("a:k").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3), Header:=xlGuess

End Sub
```